# Startup Folder, HKCU/.../Run, HKLM/.../Run. Where Else to Look to Track Down a Mysterious Login Event?

Tags: windows-7, login, boot, windows-registry

Starting *around* the time I installed the Office 2010 Beta, Whenever I login, Windows tries to open a file named "Bob", coincidentally the first part of my username. Selecting Notepad to open it, and it contains TCP/IP network settings.

I've looked for and deleted unrecognized entries in my `StartUp` folder, in `HKLM/.../CurrentVersion/Run` and in `HKCU/.../CurrentVersion/Run` with no luck.

Is there any other place I should be looking for errant entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get thee a copy of [Sysinternals' Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and use to root out all manner of things that get injected into your system.

Most likely is that there's a program attempting to start that's using an unquoted path.  The shell attempts to parse the filename and fails.  Double-check anything in Autoruns that references (or starts from) your profile.

Answer (score 2):

Check out your MSConfig (Run-->MSconfig) or grab [Autoruns from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

> This utility, which has the most
>   comprehensive knowledge of
>   auto-starting locations of any startup
>   monitor, shows you what programs are
>   configured to run during system bootup
>   or login, and shows you the entries in
>   the order Windows processes them.

Answer (score 2):

Click 'Start' and type msconfig in the search box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should bring up a dialog. On this dialog, click 'Startup'. That tab will list *everything* that is run at startup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows 7 64 bit, check HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run